# event.keyCode or event.ctrlKey not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery-events, keycode

I want to capture the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click event, the `event.keyCode` and all other stuff for detecting control clicks work fine on Chrome and Firefox. On IE am getting the following error:

> >>alert(event.keyCode);
> "Object required"

I tried detecting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click everything is fine. I tried handling the exception but nothing works. I even tried detecting the type of the return type for the `keyCode` getting number for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click am not able to capture anything out of it.

My code, which uses jQuery 1.10.2, is below:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == "17") cntrlIsPressed = true;
});
$(document).keyup(function () {
    cntrlIsPressed = false;
});
var cntrlIsPressed = false;

function call_new_url(param1) {
    if (cntrlIsPressed) {
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Can some one help me out on this?

Comment: Look for `event.ctrlKey` and `event.shiftKey`

Comment: event.ctrlKey is not getting detected in IE, no alert message is thrown. I checked the console for error messages it shows 
>>event.ctrlKey
  "Object required"
function call_new_url(job)
{
    if(event.ctrlKey)
        alert('ctrl');
    if(event.shiftKey)
        alert('shift');
}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of listening for a `keyPress` event, you can check for [`event.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/event.ctrlKey) and [`event.shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/event.shiftKey) in your click listener.

#### JavaScript:

```
$('#myLink').click(function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        console.info('Ctrl is pressed');
    } else {
        console.warn('Ctrl isn\'t pressed');
    }

    if (event.shiftKey) {
        console.info('Shift is pressed');
    } else {
        console.warn('Shift isn\'t pressed');
    }
});
```

↪ [See this code in action at JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/GS3G4/1/show/light/) or [edit](http://jsfiddle.net/GS3G4/1/) it.

Comment: thank you. but still am facing the issue, the alert is not responding at all when used with ctrl and click and that's the only scenario where the code is not working.

Comment: @user1002477 I think you'll need to post some code then. Without looking at the code, I can only guess what's going on.

Comment: @user2428112
BTW the snippet didn't work for me in IE.
Here is my code
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

`$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which=="17")
        cntrlIsPressed = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(){
    cntrlIsPressed = false;
});

var cntrlIsPressed = false;


function call_new_url(param1)
{
    if(cntrlIsPressed)
    {
       window.open("http://www.google.com");
    }
}`

Comment: event.which is also not recognized on IE

`function call_new_url(job)
{
    alert(event.which);
}`